# Has our official stance on badge progress reports changed?

Tags: discussion, badges

I've long wondered why the badge page for things like Copy Editor don't show "X edits done out of 500". Turns out we had [a reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports), though I strongly disagree with it. Note many popular metagaming systems such as Steam and iOS Game Center now offer the ability to track progress.

However, we've recently started showing badge progress...in a fairly unintuitive place:
[image]

After unlocking Strunk and White you get:

[image]

I'm sure this was in part implemented to promote the use of the Review tab, but are we ready to **just plain show progress toward badges on the badge pages**, where it is most discoverable and logical? I'd note that it's possible to find a user's progress via the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) in an exceedingly obtuse manner, and a number of the pre-baked queries are regarding [badge progress](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries).

Comment: FWIW - I asked about this very issue on [Game Dev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10672/why-not-show-progress-towards-achievements-badges)

Comment: I meant to answer this question with a slightly extended version of [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117333/160166), but since this was closed before I could hit submit, I posted the answer to the other similar question. In short: Raymond Chen must've started reviewing and editing posts :/ Seriously though, the improvements to `/review` and the progress reports were implemented by Waffles and is totally kickass, unlike public flag-weight.

Answer (score 2):

Now we have. Most badges will gave be in the format `done/needed`. For example:

[image]

As you can see in the top right corner, I have done  57 edits out of the 500 needed. There isn't any percentages anymore probably to allow users to track their progress more easily than before. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)