# Badge progress access

Tags: feature-request, badges, review, badge-progress

Where are the 'Badge progress stats' accessible from?

At the moment I have to:

1. Access the review page
2. Access a review queue
3. Point the progress bar

Is there any other way?

I suggest to let these stats be accessible from the badge tab of the user profile.

[image: badge progress stats]

Comment: Not today, but the developers are busy amazing us every day, so maybe tomorrow.

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you add comments and remarks besides your downvote.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117330/has-our-official-stance-on-badge-progress-reports-changed