# Check vote count on competing answer

Tags: discussion, vote-count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badge progress reports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports)
>   [More badge progress indicators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112102/more-badge-progress-indicators)

How to count votes those were used on competing answers?

I want to count my votes, which I were voted on my competing answers for Sportsmanship badge.

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: It means I want to count my votes, which I were voted on my competing answers...[Sportsmanship Badge]

Comment: @ArjunMane There isn't an easy way to do that.

Comment: @Yah - Begs the question - is there a hard way to do that? :P

Comment: @Lix Going through each question you answered and checking if you've upvoted competing answers would be the hard way.

Comment: @ArjunMane [This SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65472/how-close-am-i-to-the-sportsmanship-badge) might interest you, but SEDE data aren't always fresh.

Comment: What you *could* do, if you were desperate, is to visit every question you've answered, and look for whether you've upvoted any competing answers. Now, since that information is shown to you on the page, you *could* automate this process using your favorite web application testing framework... but I don't know how happy The Powers That Be would be with this!