# Badges accomplishment status display

Tags: feature-request, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [More badge progress indicators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112102/more-badge-progress-indicators)

Is it possible to make something like:

[image]

Well, I think of course it's possible, so could developers do that? ))) I think it would be more informative and interesting to see your progress.

Comment: Some badges are awarded multiple times. So displaying progress could be troublesome.

Comment: @AzizShaikh Why? You display the progress for one, then when you get it, it displays the progress for the second one... no?

Comment: @Alenanno Which one? Most recent, Most viewed, Most voted, Most active? I didn't say that it cannot be done. I think it is doable but the effort may not provide that much value.

Comment: @AzizShaikh You mean the multiple requirements? I see...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is implemented for the reviewing badges. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats).

These badges require your effort (reviewing) so you have a direct effect on the progress.

There are several issues with progress indicators for these badges:

- They can be awarded for each question and answer, so each of your questions and answers should have a separate badge progress block that distracts from the purpose of the site.
- These badges depend on votes of other users, so you have no direct influence on the progress (other than providing good content). So the use of these progress indicators is a bit questionable.
- Besides, you can very easy calculate the progress for these badges because of their dependency of the votes.

So I don't think we need a progress indicator for these badges.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [app](https://stackapps.com/questions/2982/stinkingbadges-track-your-progress-towards-long-term-badges) for this.

Though like you I think it would be good to somehow integrate progress into SO itself, either as you suggested or on the badge solo page, e.g. here

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1286/archaeologist