# Dead link trouble

Tags: discussion, edits, hyperlinks, broken-link, link-rot

While going through several answers and comments I found that several of those have dead links for example [This Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112106/163149) have [A link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1704/how-close-am-i-to-sportsmanship-badge) and this is a [comment link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31265/) etc.

Like for answer we can edit them. But what should we mention there? And comment can't even be edited. So what should be done for this?

Answer (score 3):

For comments flag as `Obsolete` or use `Other` and briefly describe what is wrong with that comment.

For answers:

if you gained edit privileges try to find a working replacement link - if you can't find one consider editing and removing the link + add what you've done to the edit summary.

if you do not have edit privileges - suggest an edit ( if you can find a working link) or flag for moderators attention and explain what is wrong.

Comment: Or just suggest an edit if I don't have edit privileges?

Comment: @hims056 that's correct!