# Option to dismiss a single mod flag

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dismiss flags on the same posts with different validities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81407/dismiss-flags-on-the-same-posts-with-different-validities)

When handling flags as a moderator they cannot be handled specifically but only all flags on a post at once.

This is usually sufficient, since most likely they are all helpful. However, there are some cases where a really bad answer is flagged as "not an answer" a few times but also has one "PLZ HELP ME" flag from the OP. In this case we now have two solutions:

- Decline all flags
- Mark all flags as helpful (either manually or by deleting the post)

Obviously both cases are bad. When declining them you decline a bunch of perfectly valid flags, possible with a message that is only directed to the OP's flag. When not declining it you mark an extremely crappy flags as helpful, causing a positive flag weight to the creator of that flag.

So it would be useful if there was an option to handle a single flag without touching the other flags on the post.

The most comfortable solutions would be not integrating this in the flag queue page but rather add it to the "show flag history" page of a post by adding a link to handle each flag.

Comment: Damnit, not displayed as similar while posting it but right after posting it...

Comment: Later I realized this wasn't the right solution: [Remove flag weight and flag validity already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106614)

Comment: @Gilles: Flag weight still exists internally.

Comment: I know. I requested it to be removed altogether, as a consequence of removing flag validity. My request was marked [meta-tag:status-completed] even though it wasn't carried out. By the way, I shouldn't say “right solution”: even without flag validity, sometimes it would be useful to give different *feedback* on pending flags on the same post.